# I can't upload my Unity game to Google Play

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-console

I can't upload my Unity game to Google Play.

Android App Bundle is not signed error.

I was trying to upload my game to google play console but i am getting application package not signed error. I searched on the internet but couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch this [video](https://youtu.be/sPrI_ukdT-A?t=150) at 2:30 to create the keystore files. Do not delete the files or you won't be able to update the app on play store.

Comment: There is a tools section at 3:31 in the video, but it is not in my program.

Comment: @Antisra7 Skip that part. Uploading to the play store is little bit different to the video.